Python / Pytorch combining unequal data frames to create a value, label pair
I have two data frames:
df1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
df2 = [a,b]

I want to combine them so that the resulting
df[0] = [[1,2,3], a].
My final goal is to be able to do something like:
numbers, letter  = df[0]
--> numbers = [1,2,3], letter = a


You can achieve this by using pandas to create the data frames and then combine them. Here's a step-by-step solution:
1.Create the two data frames.
2.Concatenate them along the columns.
3.Extract and unpack the desired row.
import pandas as pd

# Create the data frames
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b'])

# Combine the data frames
df_combined = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

# Extract the desired row and unpack it
numbers, letter = df_combined.iloc[0, :-1].tolist(), df_combined.iloc[0, -1]

print(numbers)  # Output: [1, 2, 3]
print(letter)   # Output: a

